# Twilio: How to avoid verification of number in twilio api

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am using `twilio-API` for voice call . But to make a voice call it is required to verify both the caller and receiver phone number . Is is possible to skip the receiver no. verification step in `twilio-API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The reason it asks you for verification is because you're most likely running on a trial account, which will limit things you can do with your account.

If you upgrade your account, you won't need to verify the numbers you can call to.

You can read more about the limitations on trial accounts [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-).

Hope this helps you